# Is Nityananda Prabhu incarnation of Lord Balarama?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

Is there any scriptural evidence that Nitya Nanda Prabhu (Nitai of Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya) is an incarnation of Lord Balarama?

They also claim that Advaita Acharya is an incarnation of Maha Vishnu. To me this is a bit far fetched. But want to know if there is any scriptural evidence or is it just a belief based on faith?

Comment: What is the name of that *Advaita Acharya*?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think his name itself is Advaita Acharya.

Comment: Thank you @Destroyer. Yes, his name is Advaita Acharya. Can brahma jignasa or any Gaudiya Vaishnavas help?

Comment: Your question has been answered at the above link posted by *SwiftPushkar*. To my knowledge there is no scriptural evidence that Nitai and Advaita Acarya are avataras of Lord Vishnu. That they are avataras of Balarama (Nitai) and combination of Maha Vishnu and Sadashiva (Advaita Acarya) is confirmed in the Gaudiya Vaishnava work *Caitanya caritamrita*, and it's confirmed by the Lord Caitanya himself, apparently. Lord Caitanya is Lord Krishna himself, and thus he knew that they are avataras.